# Is there a QNX virtual machine for QEMU

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, qemu, qnx

I am developing on a Windows machine but I have to test it on a PowerPC running QNX. I don't have constant access to the PowerPC, and I just can use it for some test. I was wondering if I could debug my code on a QNX virtual machine on QEMU emulating the PowerPC.

I have found the QEMU binaries for Windows [here](http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/) but I can not find the QNX VM for QEMU. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your target platform to be PPC all the time. Build your software for x86, test it and recompile it for PPC when you have access to the device. Just make sure your code is portable.

Use VMWare Player or Workstation to install QNX and configure your tools to use the virtual machine for build and debug. That will speed up your development process dramatically!

Comment: The problem is that my code is talking to another software on that PPC. I can't rebuild that other software for x86 because I don't have the source code.

Comment: Well, you need to install PowerPC version of QNX into QEMU then. Here's a starting point: http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.qemu/wiki/NeutrinoAsGuestInQEMU